# Bounty: self answered question

Tags: discussion, bounties

I have a currently open **bounty** in Magento site [Magento2 - missing adminhtml custom block after upgrade to 2.2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/216622/magento2-missing-adminhtml-custom-block-after-upgrade-to-2-2) & I have solved the problem myself

I can accept my answer as valid, but I am not sure what to do with the bounty points

I am not asking to be able to give the points to myself, but I don't think it is right to give points to other answers which won't solve the problem... so, what's the right thing to do? Give the points to the most valid answer? Don't give any points?

Comment: You're going to want to read the bounty FAQ... it explains how bounties work. https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065/284336 depending on answer scores, you may not get a choice.

Comment: @Catija FAQ is not really relevant, OP appears to know and understand how it works. The question is about what is the best course of action, not how to perform it or if it's possible. (Which was already discussed before though.)

Comment: @ShadowWizard  That isn't clear to me.... the OP seems to think that not awarding it is an option, but if one of the other answers gets to +3, the system will award half of it automatically.

Comment: I believe he is aware of that, by "Don't give any points" he probably means just not award the bounty manually, and let the system decide. @Catija